# How to remove all items of a Mongo collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have seen that to remove all items of a Mongo collection using JavaScript I should use :

```
DockerStats.remove(); //where DockerStats is my collection
```

So my goal is to purge the DB every 20sec so I did the following code :

```
  setInterval(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
    DockerStats.remove();
    console.log("ok")
  }),20000);
```

But when I start the app I had +/- 1000items then despite the terminal wrote 2 times "ok" I still have more than 1000items so it doesn't work because even if I check right after the "ok" I have more than 1000items and the number is always growing up.

So maybe I'm removing the items with the wrong way ?

Comment: I think you have to pass in an object to `remove` for it to remove everything. So you can do `DockerStats.remove({})` and it should drop the collection.

Comment: @TimRoberts you are right ! You can put an answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#remove-all-documents-from-a-collection), you need to pass in an empty object to delete the whole collection. So, the below would remove all students from the Students collection:

```
Students.remove({})
```

I think this is because if you want to remove everything and start over you would use the `drop` method and recreate it, which the docs says is more performant.